# How do you say "(noun) is more/less (adj) to (person A) than to (person B)"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

For example "That movie was less scary to me than it was to you."

The best I can manage is something like "私にとってよりあの映画はあなたにとってこわい。” but it feels off, and checking with Google doesn't seem to turn up any such constructions. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This construction in English does not work well in Japanese.  A direct translation will not sound very natural even though it might successfully convey the idea.  Native speakers might say:

> 「あの映画{えいが}は、私{わたし}よりもあなたの方{ほう}が怖{こわ}いと思{おも}った（みたいね）。」
>
> 「私よりもあなたの方が、あの映画は怖いと思った（んじゃないの/でしょう）。」
>
> 「私はあなたほど（には）あの映画が怖いと思わなかった。」
>
> 「あなたは私[以上]{いじょう}にあの映画を怖いと思ったようですね。」

Expressing this idea by using 「にとって」 twice (just because "to" is used twice in English) would make it sound pretty wordy (or at least wordier than J-learners might think).  If you wanted to use 「にとって」, you could use it just once and say:

> 「私よりも、あなたにとってあの映画は怖かったんだろうね。」

Comment: 「私はあなたほど～～なかった」みたいな構文でもできます？

Comment: できますって、そういう例文も書けっていう意味？ほな追加するわ。おおきに～。

Comment: ()がないほうが正しい文であるし、また文法的に言えば3番目以外正しくない。

Comment: Wouldn't it be closer to natural to say something like 「◯◯の方はその映画が怖かった」